# How to validate against any pod security policy during deployment of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, elastic-stack

I have deployed the Bitnami helm chart of elasticsearch on the Kubernetes environment.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/elasticsearch

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error for the coordinating-only pod. However, the cluster is restricted.

**Pods "elasticsearch-elasticsearch-coordinating-only-5b57786cf6-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy:
[spec.initContainers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value: true: Privileged containers are not allowed]; Deployment does not have minimum availability.**

I there anything I need to adapt/add-in default **values.yaml**?

Any suggestion to get rid of this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't validate if your cluster is restricted with some security policy. In your situation someone (assuming administrator) has blocked the option to run privileged containers for you.

Here's an example of how pod security policy blocks privileged containers:

```yaml
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  privileged: false  # Don't allow privileged pods!
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny

----
```

What is require for you is to have appropriate `Role` with a `PodSecurityPolicy` resource and `RoleBinding` that will allow you to run privileged containers.

This is very well explained in kubernetes documentation at [Enabling pod security policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#enabling-pod-security-policies)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I guess then I need  "ClusterRole" and "ClusterRoleBinding" because I have an elasticsearch pod that is affecting the whole cluster !! I have dedicated "logging" as namespace but elasticsearch will communicate with "fluentd" which will be running on all available nodes inside the cluster.

Comment: Correct, if you need something affecting whole cluster then ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding is the way to go :)

Comment: CR, CRB, PSP is created and applied. but cannot resolve still above error.

Comment: @kishu I checked your deployed policies and I can see that you are still disallowing the privileged containers. Can you set `privileged` to `true` and try again?

Comment: Thanks for the guideline. It has been fixed using a bit different approach

Answer (score 0):

so the solution was to set the following parameter in values.yaml file then deploy simply.
Don't need to create any role or pod security policy.

```
sysctlImage:
  enabled: false

curator:
  enabled: true
  rbac:
    # Specifies whether RBAC should be enabled
    enabled: true
  psp:
    # Specifies whether a podsecuritypolicy should be created
    create: true
```

Also run this command on each node:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144 && sysctl -w fs.file-max=65536
```